# How do I use unobtrusive validation mode and jquery in a bundle instead of script resource mapping?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, unobtrusive-validation

To avoid receiving the jquery unobtrusive validation error...

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping
>   for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive).

... I have the following code in my Application_Start Global.asax:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
    Path = "~/Scripts/jquery.js",
    DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
});
```

That works, but I'd rather use script bundles because I can bundle both jquery, jquery-ui and other scripts together,  plus I like the scriptbundle {version} functionality.  So I use this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/alljs").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.js",
    "~/Scripts/myscript.js"));
```

The problem is that the unubtrusive validation mode requires the scriptResourceMapping be used, even though there are other, potentially more efficient ways to include the jquery files.

Is there any way to do this without the user of scriptresourcemapping?